# Purely Inseparable Morphism of Schemes (Ex. from Liu's "AG & AC")

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

My questions refer to Exercise 5.3.9 from  Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" (page 208):

[image]

I have two questions:

How to show in (a) that

$K(Y) \to K(X)$ pure inseparable implies $f$ purely inseparable

My considerations:

As @Laurent Moret-Bailly stated in his comment below it is neccessary to assume that $X$ dominates $Y$ (otherwise the extension $K(X)/K(Y)$ don't make any sense since in such case this map in genereal would not exist).

By definition $f: X \to Y$ is called purely inseparable if $f$ injective and if for every $x ∈ X$, the extension of residue fields $k(f(x)) → k(x)$
is a purely inseparable extension.

We obtain following diagram 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
O_{Y,f(x)}  @>{}>> O_{X,x} \\
@VVV  @VVV  \\
K(Y)=O_{Y, \eta_Y} @>{}>> K(X)=O_{X, \eta_X}
\end{CD}
$$

By finiteness & purely separateness we have $K(X) = K(Y)[a^{1/n}]$ for appropriate $a \in K(Y)$. The question is how this strucure can be "transfered"  to $O_{Y,f(x)}/m_{f(x)}=k(f(x)) \to k(x)= O_{X,x}/m_x$?

Honestly, I have no idea.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336208/purely-inseparable-morphism-characterization You should wait a week, or at least a few days, before cross-posting at another site. And when you do, you should link, at every site where you post, a link to every other site where you post.

Comment: Clearly one must assume $f$ surjective.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: Yes, if we succeed in showing that $K(Y)→K(X)$ pure inseparable is equivalent to "$f$ purely inseparable then since then $K(Y)→K(X)$ neccessary algebraic we conclude that the generic point $\eta_X$ is mapped by $f$ to generic $\eta_Y$ of $Y$. So the image if $f$ is then dense (since $Y$ integral) and closed (by properness). So $f$ is then indeed also surjective and 2) is done.

Comment: Do you see a way how to show "$K(Y)→K(X)$ pure inseparable $\Rightarrow$ $f$ purely inseparable"?

Comment: What I mean is just that the definition of "purely inseparable" does not imply that $f$ is dominating (e.g. every immersion is purely inseparable). If $f$ is not dominating, the extension $K(Y)\to K(X)$ does not even make sense.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: Thank you for this important point. I updated the question

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: hmmm another idea might be (motivated by observation that every algebraic fieldextension $L/K$ can be splitted in $K \subset M \subset L$ where $M/K$ is separable extension and $L/M$ purely inseparable). So if I try to transfer this idea to our schematic problem I would like to argue as follows: There exist a "mysterious" scheme $W$ such that $f$ factors as $X \to W \to Y$ where $g:X \to W$ is a purely inseparable morphism and $h: W \to Y$ is a "seprarable morphism" (I don't know if such notation exist:

Comment: I mean that it is dual to purely inseparable: all extensions $k(h(x)) \to k(x)$ are separable). My hope is (if such factorization realy exist) then in our situation $W \cong Y$ using the assumption that $K(Y) \to K(X)$ purely inseparable. Can it work or is the idea too optimistic?

Comment: The point is that if we have such factorization then $K(Y) \subset K(W) \subset K(X)$ so $K(Y)=K(W)$ so $h$ birational, proper, finite and so on. Excuse, I think that at this point I lost a bit my overview but thinking about Zariski's MT I guess (better: hope) that there is a variation of it providing that $h$ is an iso... there are a lot of formulations of ZMT (the famous about fiber connectedness) but is there some giving an isomorphism criterion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A caution: it's not necessarily true that $K(X)=K(Y)[a^{1/n}]$ - for instance, $\Bbb F_2(x,y)\subset \Bbb F_2(x,y)[x^{1/2},y^{1/2}]$ is a purely inseparable finite extension which is not generated by a single element.

Now on to the real problem. The first thing to do is to note that we may reduce to the case of both $X,Y$ affine - making the reduction to $Y$ affine is clear, and then the fact that finite morphisms are affine implies the reduction for $X$. So we may write $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec} B$ for $A,B$ both noetherian integral domains and $B$ integrally closed (by normality). $f$ finite implies that $A$ is a finite $B$-module, so now we can pick a finite set of generators $\{z_i\}_{i\in I}$ for $A$ as a $B$-algebra.

**Lemma**: Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain and $F=Frac(R)$. Let $F\subset K$ be a finite field extension. Then for any $\alpha\in K$ integral over $R$, the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $\alpha$ is actually in $R[x]$.

**Proof**: As $\alpha$ is integral, there's a monic polynomial $f\in R[x]$ with $f(\alpha)=0$. But by the inclusion $R[x]\subset F[x]$, $f$ is also a polynomial in $F$ which vanishes on $\alpha$. So it's divisible by $m(x)$, and we may write $f=gm$. As all roots of $m$ are roots of $f$, all roots of $m$ are integral over $R$. As the coefficients of $m$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in these roots, the coefficients of $m$ are again integral over $R$. As $R$ is integrally closed, these coefficients are actually in $R$, and thus we've shown that $m(x)\in R[x]$. $\blacksquare$

By definition of a purely inseparable extension, every element of $Frac(A)$ has a minimal polynomial over $Frac(B)$ of the form $x^{p^n}-b$. Applying the lemma above to the $z_i$ which are integral over $B$, we see that each $z_i$ satisfies the relation $x^{p^{n_i}}-b_i$ for $b_i\in B$ and $n_i\in \Bbb Z_{> 0}$.

To show that $f$ is purely inseparable, it suffices to compute $A/\mathfrak{m}$ for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset B$ and to show it's a local ring with residue field a purely inseparable extension of $B/\mathfrak{m}$ (this suffices because it shows that the fibers are all single points, which implies $f$ injective). But this is clear - for every $b_i\notin \mathfrak{m}$, we adjoin a $p^{n_i}$th root of something in the field $B/\mathfrak{m}$, and for every $b_i\in\mathfrak{m}$, we get some nilpotents in $A/\mathfrak{m}$. So $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal consisting of the nilpotents we added, and we're done.

Comment: By definition $f$ is injective if it injective and $k(f(x)) → k(x)$ is purely inseparable for every $x \in X$. I guess that if $\mathfrak{p} \subset B$ is not maximal you just localize $A$ and $B$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ and argue as in case of maximal prime ideals,right? (since localizing doesn't change the fields of fractions)

Comment: Another point: Do you know if there exist also a way to argue in spirit of Zariski's Main theorem as I tried to explain during my correspondence with Prof. Moret-Bailly above? (my motivition is because the previous chapter Liu dealed with ZMT so I thought that it might be here also useful :)...

Comment: Namely to factor $f$ as $X→W→Y$ where $g:X→W$ is a purely inseparable morphism and $h:W→Y$ is a "seprarable morphism" (so dual to purely inseparable: all extensions $k(h(x))→k(x)$ are separable). If such factorization exist then it induces $ K(Y)⊂K(W)⊂K(X)$ so K(Y)=K(W)$ so h must be neccessary ***birational*** (since $K(Y)⊂K(W)$ would be by construction separable and $K(Y)⊂K(X)$ by assumption purely insep), proper, finite and so on. And then there might be exist a variant of ZMT that in this case already $W \cong Y$ holds.

Comment: Do you know if something like this could also work? The cruical point (beside h iso) if such $W$ with desired properties exist... my suspicion is some kind of a "generalized normalization" of $Y$ not wrt it's function field $K(Y)$ (since $Y$ is already normal) but an appropriate separable extension of $K(Y)$. This $W$ should futhermore have a universal property forcing $f$ factorize throgh $W$. Might it work? I don't know if such concept exist...

Comment: I would say that the reason this is in the Zariski's Main Theorem section would be that part (b) of the question can be turned in to a 1-liner based on Stein factorization, which is closely related to ZMT. Stein factorization lets you write a proper morphism as a contraction of the connected components of the fiber followed by a finite map - applying (a) to the finite map gives the geometrically connectedness of the fibers. I don't see how your proposed factorization of the field extension gets you to skip the work of the post, which is really not too bad (an easy reduction and one lemma).

Comment: no no, your answer was great, I was just a bit curious about a possible universal property of a kind of "generalized normalization". I was thinking in following way: Assume we are searching for another factorization $X \to W \to Y$ such that we swap the roles of my previous $h$ and $g$; namely $f= h \circ g$ where $g:X \to W$ is separable and $h: W \to Y$ purely inseparable. This looks nice to me because now I may inpose a candidate for $W$. I claim that $W$ is the normalization of $Y$ ***wrt $K(X)$*** (instead of classical normalization wrt $K(Y)$.

Comment: Now the cruical part: What might be the universal property of $W$? Intuitively it would be funny if it would be that every morphism $Z \to Y$ with $K(Z)=K(X)$ must factorize through $W$ (sounds plausible, but I nowhere found if such demand could work and impose a meaningsful construction). If we have it then $f$ factorize and $g$ is an iso: $W$ is normal, $g$ birational and finite (since $f$ finite and $h$ separable, since proper). So iso.

Comment: Do you know if such"normalizations wrt to field extensions of function fields" exist and do they fullfill such universal properies concerning unique factorizations as the classical normalizations does?