# Generalization of Normalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question that arises from [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293355/purely-inseparable-morphism-of-schemes-ex-from-lius-ag-ac) former thread of mine (look up in the comments to see the motivation):

Let $X$ be a scheme. It is well known that there exist a so called "normalization" $n: \overline{X} \to X$ where $\overline{X}$ is normal and has following universal property:

If $f: Y \to X$ is an arbitrary scheme morphism and $Y$ normal then $f$ factorizes through $\overline{X}$.

Now I'm curious if there exist a generalization of the "Normalization" procedure of a scheme in following sense:

Let $X$ be again a scheme with function field $K(X)$. Let $L/K(X)$ be an arbitrary (hope, that it's not too general) field extension of $K(X)$. Then there exist a morphism $m: W \to X$ with certain universal property blabla so that if $f: Y \to X$ with $Y$ has property blabla then $F$ factorize through $W$.

Does such construction exist? Sure, in case $L=K(X)$ this $W$ is exactly the normalization of $X$ but what about general extension of $K(X)$? Or is it hopeless?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what blabla is and what is the connection between blabla and $L$ ?

Comment: There is a notion of normalization of an integral scheme in an algebraic extension of its function field. See Ravi Vakil's lecture notes or Quing Liu's algebraic geometry book.

Comment: @Roland: Here I'm not sure which (weakest as possible) properties for $Y$ should be allowed such that the universal property might work. I'm not sure. If I draw analogy to normality and try to generalize it a natural suspicion might be that such factorization over $W$ exist iff $Y$ maybe normal and it's function field is extension of $L$. Or is it to strong? I don't know

Comment: @ParthivBasu: Yes, in Liu I found that in case of an extension $L/K(X)$ there always exist a scheme $Z$ with induced map $Z \to X$ and $K(Z)=L$. Essentially in ring language locally $Z$ is exactly the integral closure of $X$ wrt to $L$. The problem is that there was nothing mentioned about a universal property which such construction has

Comment: As Roland mentioned, it is important to state the property you desire. Here is the deal. If you have a morphism $W \to X$ of integral schemes, where $W$ is normal, which satisfies the following universal property 

 - *for any dominant morphism $Y\to X$, where $Y$ is integral and normal, there exists a unique morphism $Y\to W$ such that $Y \to W \to X = Y \to X$*. Then it must be true that $K(W) \cong K(X)$.

Comment: Which role might here play the extension $L/K(X)$?