# Fibered surface has connected fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, k3-surfaces

I throwed a look into C. Liedtke's paper [SEMI-STABLE  REDUCTION  FOR  CURVES](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/mordellsem/Notes/L12.pdf) and have some problems to understand an argument (page 1):

Let $S$ be  a  connected  Dedekind  scheme.   We  denote  by $K=K(S)$ it's function field $\mathcal{O}_{S, \eta}$.

**Definition 2.**
An arithmetic  surface is an integral, projective, and flat $S$-scheme $\pi: X \to S$ of relative dimension $1$, where $S$ is as before.

Clearly, the generic fiber
$X_{\eta}$
of an arithmetic surface is an integral and
projective curve over the function field $K(S)$ of $S$.
Conversely, if $S = Spec R$
for a DVR $R$
, then an arithmetic surface over $S$ is a model of its generic fiber.

Given  a  normal  proper  and  geometrically  connected  curve $C$
over  the function field $K(S)$ of $S$ ,  we seek “good” models over $S$.
For instance,  if we  choose  a  projective  embedding  of
$C$ into  some $\mathbb{P}^n_{K(S)}$ then  its  Zariski closure in $\mathbb{P}^n_{S}$
is an arithmetic surface (where the $S$ -flatness uses that
$S$ is Dedekind).  Hence,  we can always find an arithmetic surface with generic
fiber $C (=X_{\eta}$. Since $S$ is normal and $C$ is reduced and geometrically connected over
$K(S)$ , so $H^0(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ is a finite purely inseparable extension field of
$K(S)$, it
follows from considerations with Stein factorization (whose fibers are always
geometrically connected) that any such arithmetic surface has geometrically
connected fibers over $S$, (**???**) i.e. all fibers $X_s \cong f^{-1}(s)$ for all $s \in S$ are geometrically connected.

**Question**:

Why the assumption that $H^0(C, \mathcal{O}_C)= H^0(X_{\eta}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{\eta}})$ is a finite purely inseparable extension field of
$K(S)$ imply using Stein factorisation that every fiber $X_s$ is geometrically connected? I don't understand the argument.

We can assume that $S= Spec(A)$ is affine and $A$ is a dvr with generic point $\eta$ and closed $s \in S$ and we need to show that $X_s$ at first is connected. First of all by Stein factorisation $\pi: X \to S$ splits into $ X \xrightarrow{f} Y' \xrightarrow{g} S$ with $Y'=Spec(\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X).$ Then $L:=H^0(X_{\eta}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{\eta}})$ is a finite purely inseparable extension field of
$K(S)$.

Because $f$ has by definition geometrically connected fibers, it suffice to show that $g$ is bijective. And this is exactly the problem.

A *classical result* tells that if $X$ is an algebraic variety over $k$, and let $K/k$ be an
algebraic purely inseparable extension, then the canonical map $X_K \to X$ is a homeomorphism (see for example Liu's Algebraic Geometry page 89, Prop. 3.2.7 ). In Liu (page 350, Corollary 8.3.6(b) is suggested to use this result to conclude that $g$ is bijective, but I don't understand how this mentioned classical result can be here applied.

Rmk: I know that another way to prove the claim using formal functions theorem works as well. The motivation behind this question is how to use here the assumption on purely inseparability of $L$ over $K(S)$ as guided in Liu's book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly on the correct track with writing $\pi$ as a composite $X\stackrel{f}\to Y'\stackrel{g}\to S$ and then noting that we wish to show that $g$ is bijective. We may observe that $g:Y'\to S$ is a finite morphism of integral schemes and $S$ is locally noetherian and normal, plus $K(X)=K(Y')\supset K(S)$ is a purely inseparable extension (as $f_*\mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_{Y'}$). This means that in the terminology of Liu, it's a finite purely inseparable morphism and per exercise 5.3.9(a) it will be a homeomorphism and thus bijective. [Here's a previous post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293355/purely-inseparable-morphism-of-schemes-ex-from-lius-ag-ac/3295672#3295672) which gives the details of showing that a finite purely inseparable map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: this is a really nice argument. one side note arising from carefully reading of Liu's proof of connectedness of $X_s$ on page 350  of Corollary 8.3.6(b). going through the argumentation he concludes that $Spec O_X(X) \to Spec(A)=Y$ is bijective as a consequence of Proposition 3.2.7 applied to p.i. extension $K(S) \to L$. The statement of Proposition 3.2.7 I have quoted in my post above in the next-to-last paragraph. do you see how Liu's argument works at that point?

Comment: Unfortunately, I not see the connection between Prop. 3.2.7 and bijectivity of $Spec O_X(X) \to Spec(A)=Y$. The latter hasn't the structure of a base change map. nor I also don't see any possibility to apply Prop. 3.2.7 to fiber restrictions $(Spec O_X(X))_s \to Speck(s)$ (with $s \in S$), because $k(s)$ is in general not a $K(S)$-variety. do you have an idea?