# Purely inseparable on function fields implies injective on topological spaces.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, and $X, Y$ be two varieties(i.e. geometrically integral, separated and of finite type over $k$) of same dimension.

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a dominant morphism which induces a purely inseparable field extension $K(X)/K(Y)$. Can we deduce $f$ is injective on topological spaces? If not could you share a counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: This is already false for the case that $f$ is birational - consider a blowup, for instance.

Comment: @KReiser You are right. But I saw a proposition: Under conditions I have posted, if $Y$ is additionally normal, then there is a $g:Y_{p^r}\to X$ such that $g\circ f=F^r$ for some $r$. (here $F$ is the frobenius on $Y$). So if these varieties are complete, then all maps are surjective. Since $F^r$ is bijective, we deduce $f$ is bijective. There must be something wrong. But could you find why?

Comment: If you "saw a proposition" claiming this, it would be a good idea to add that context to your post, along with information like what text you saw this in, where the proposition is in the text, etc. [Depending on the adjectives you add, something like what you want can be true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293355/).